# jQuery - reset change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Input file, so when I upload an Image and then remove it, I can't upload the same image again, only another different

**addimg**:

```
obj2.on('change', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('border',"4px dotted #bdc3c7");
    var objid = $(this).parents('.drop').attr("id");
    var files = e.target.files;
    var file = files[0];
    if (files && files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $("#" + objid).find(".addCont").css('visibility', 'hidden');
            $("#" + objid).css('background-image', 'url(' + e.target.result + ')');
            $("#" + objid).find('.imgmenucontainer').css('visibility', 'visible'); 
        }
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    }
});
```

**remove**:

```
$(".custombtnremove").click(function(){
    var objid = $(this).parents('.drop').attr('id');
    $("#" + objid).css('background-image', '');
    $("#" + objid).find('.imgmenucontainer').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $("#" + objid).find(".addCont").css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

So I assume It has to be something with the change event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empty your input file after you remove an image.

```
$(".custombtnremove").click(function(){
    //previous code here
    //reset input file
    $(obj2).val(""); //-> or obj2.val(""); if obj2 is already a jquery object.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try that case?:

```
1. upload file A
2. remove file A
3. upload file B
4. remove file B
5. upload file A
```

if that works fine, you have to add in your remove event:

```
$(obj2).val("");
```

The cause is you don't change data to comparison with previous the same data...well event `change` is not fired. Solution: after delete - set data to empty and all should works fine. In your `change` event you can add an additional condition for `""` val.